# JMeter CSVRead in Non Gui Mode does not read the file

Tags: jmeter

I use JMeter 2.11.

I build my Test with nesting files and so on. With CSV Data Set it did not work. But i found a solution with the JMeter function __CSVRead and it works fine in GUI mode.

Now I have to run this test in non-GUI mode and it does not work.
I try to read a CSV file with some urls and want to send a normal HTTP request zu this adress.
in my HTTP request I set for server name: ${__CSVRead(${file},0)} Port: 7080

In GUI mode he can read the file in non-GUI not. I don´t know why.

Result in the log: 
1406123833303,1077,asd,Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException,Non HTTP response message: Connection to http://:7080 refused,jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group 1-1,text,false,2213,0

Please don´t say I have to take "CSV Data Set" it really doesn´t work with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

My expectation that in GUI mode you're using relative path in your `${file}` variable.

The easiest option is switch to using full path instead of relative.

Alternatively you can check where JMeter expects CSV file to be present and copy it over. It can be done, i.e. using [Beanshell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) with the following code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

File file = new File(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + vars.get("file"));

if (!file.exists()) {
    ResponseMessage = "Failed to locate " + vars.get("file") + " file under " + FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + " folder";
    IsSuccess = false;
    log.error(ResponseMessage);
    SampleResult.setStopTestNow(true);
}
```

The code above checks existence of file with the name stored in `${file}` variable under current JMeter working directory and if the file isn't there sampler will fail and the test will be stopped.